# Is it possible to change styles path in angular-cli dynamically - based on env variable?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In `**angular-cli.json**` I do have the following values for styles:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "./assets/css/styles.css",
    ....
]
```

I would like to change the entries dynamically based on a variable in **`environment.prod.ts`**

In other words, if a environment variable `x === true` then the assets should point the styles on CDN server e.g.:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "http://domainCDN/css/styles.css",
    "http://domainCDN/sass/theme.scss"
]
```

If not, then I would like to keep them relative e.g.

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "./assets/css/styles.css",
    "./assets/sass/theme.scss"
]
```

Comment: K.Vicent, when in angular-cli.json we add .css files in "styles" the result when we make ng build --prod is e.g. styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css that it's the union of all of them. there are no css/styles/styles.css never more

Comment: Ah! "Don’t place your local CSS files under assets folder. When we do the production build with Angular CLI, the CSS files declared in the .angular-cli.json will be minified and all styles will be bundled into a single styles.css. The assets folder is copied to the dist folder during the build process (the CSS code will be duplicated). Only place your local CSS files under assets in case you are importing them directly in the index.html." (Loiane Groner)

Comment: @Eliseo:I know about bundling and how the `ng build -prod` etc. works. The background for saving CSS under `/assets` folder is that the app is being loaded on production server where I run `ng build` from docker file, create an image and a container. The Output which is in `/dist` folder with `/assets` folder, should give the customer the ability to edit and change CSS, fonts, images the way he would like to.
But to be honest, I just can't see - in your comment - where is the point, if it's possible to change the styles path dynamically in `angular-cli.json` or not.

Comment: Well, instead of add the .css in angular-cli json, You can include in your html all the <styles> that you need. The problem is that angular-cli override the index.html. Sorry, I don't know it's possible to change the styles path dynamically in angular-cli.json or not